# Are simply connected open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ homeomorphic to an open ball?

Tags: general-topology

Let $U$ be a simply connected open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is it true that $U$ is homeomorphic to an open ball?

Comment: Yes. This follows from the Riemann mapping theorem.

Comment: I'm asking more general question.

Comment: You have changed the question after correct answers have been posted. I think it'd be better to ask a separate question for general $n$.

Comment: Since you now re-asked your follow-up question I rolled back to the previous version.

Comment: BUT, isn't the fact in the question **MUCH EASIER TO PROVE** than the Riemann mapping theorem?  (A snipe: is the empty set simply connected?)

Comment: @GEdgar: Proving this without the Riemann mapping theorem was the subject of [this MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66048/riemann-mapping-theorem-for-homeomorphisms).

Comment: see also Pedro's answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064066/is-every-path-connected-open-subset-of-mathbbr2-homeomorphic-to-mathbbr/1064068#1064068

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is the [Riemann mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem). You get much more than a homeomorphism: you get a biholomorphic map.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  In fact, more can be said... [The Riemann Mapping Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) states that the homeomorphism can be taken to be biholomorphic (as a complex map), if $U \neq \mathbb{C}$.  See [this link](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~richardt/414/414-ch7.pdf) for a much more detailed treatment and proof.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Riemann mapping theorem that's true iff U is a simply connected nonempty open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is **a strict subset**. That is, $U\subsetneq \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ is also homeomorphic to an open ball.

Comment: That's because the asker changed the question...