# Is every open, bounded and simply connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ essentially a ball?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, bounded and simply connected. I wonder if the answer to the following question is known:

Is there a homeomorphism $\Omega\to \operatorname{B}_1(0)$, where $\operatorname{B}_R(0)$ is the open ball (in the topology induced by the metric) with radius $R$ around $0\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

The Poincare conjecture comes to mind, but it only concerns manifolds without border, as far as I understand.

Thanks for any hints to literature, theorems or counterexamples etc... :)

Comment: $B_2(0)\setminus\bar{B}_1(0)$ is open, bounded, simply connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ but not a ball.

Comment: in dimension 2 this is true : it is the riemann mapping theorem

Comment: Those are both answers, not comments!

Comment: @achille The set you considered is punctured.

Comment: Might be worth looking at the higher homotopy groups. Every path in $B_2(0) \setminus \overline B_1(0)$ contracts to a point, but there is a surface which doesn't, so the second homotopy group isn't trivial. In a convex set like the open ball, every homotopy group is trivial.

Comment: See also: [necessary and sufficient conditions  to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^m$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/283260/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$B_1(0)\setminus\{0\}$ is a counterexample when $n>2$.

Comment: Of coarse! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

In $\mathbb R^2$, yes, every open, bounded and simply connected set is homeomorphic to $B_1(0)$.

Look at [Are simply connected open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ homeomorphic to an open ball?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55107/are-simply-connected-open-sets-in-mathbbr2-homeomorphic-to-an-open-ball) and [Proof that convex open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are homeomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165629/proof-that-convex-open-sets-in-mathbbrn-are-homeomorphic)

Comment: Yes, indeed. I appologise.

Comment: Another link for the $n=2$ case, from MathOverflow, with the requirement of *not* using the Riemann mapping theorem: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66048/riemann-mapping-theorem-for-homeomorphisms.  Boundedness is unnecessary.  (A trivial remark is that nonemptiness is necessary unless that is already part of the definition of simply connected.)

Comment: I edited to make the restriction to two dimensions more obvious.