# Example of a simply connected Lipschitz domain non-homeomorphic to unit ball?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

What is example of a simply connected Lipschitz domain which is not homeomorphic to unit ball? In $R^2$, such a domain is necessarily unit disc ([Are simply connected open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ homeomorphic to an open ball?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55107/are-simply-connected-open-sets-in-mathbbr2-homeomorphic-to-an-open-ball)).

Even, I am curious to just see the example without being "Lipschitz".

Comment: Maybe $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash \{0\}$?

Comment: Right, that is the example of a simply connected domain! But this doesn't have a Lipschitz boundary? Now, if I consider a three dimensional open-annulus which is simply connected having boundry as the union of two spheres, I think this would constitute the Lipschitz domain?

Comment: I think so, indeed, since the boundary is going to be a smooth $2$-dimensional manifold.